# Cancel a command using a code with flutter

Tags: flutter

I simply want to cancel a command.
In this example, I have one button calling for two simple print commands.
Let's say I want to cancel the second one (Print("Pressed2!").
How can I do it using a code?

Best regards

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';



class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body:
    getbody(),);
  }


  Widget Press(){
    return MaterialButton(
        child: Text("Press"),
        onPressed: ()  {
          print("Pressed1!");
          print("Pressed2!");
        });
  }

  Widget getbody(){
    return Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(children: [
            Press()

          ],),
        ),
    );}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional. First declare a variable `shouldShowPrint = true`. Then wrap your print call into a conditional
`print("Pressed1!"); if (shouldShowPrint){ print("Pressed2!"); }`

And when you don’t want to print the second text, make your `shouldShowPrint` variable `false`.

Comment: I was thinking of that. Thank you.